# How to make the background of NavigationContainer transparent in react-navigation v5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am trying to make the background of `NavigationContainer` transparent for making the items under bottom to be visible , but it is not working in my case. Please do help if you know how to achieve this in react native.Following is my code for `Tab.Navigator`

```
 import {NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme} from '@react-navigation/native

 <TabNavigator.Navigator
    tabBarOptions={{
    showLabel: false,
    style: {
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      marginBottom: 15,
      borderRadius: 15,
      marginHorizontal: 10,
      height:60
      },
    activeTintColor: constants.APP_THEME_COLOR,
    inactiveTintColor: constants.APP_WHITE_COLOR,
    keyboardHidesTabBar: true,
  }}>
  ....
  const navTheme = {
   ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
   ...DefaultTheme.colors,
  background: 'red',
  },
};
function App() {
  return (
   <NavigationContainer theme={navTheme}>
     <SwitchNavigator />
  </NavigationContainer>
 );
```

}

I have tried `background: 'transparent'` ,but it is not working.Please refer the screenshot attached.

1. background:red

[image]

2.background:transparent

[image]

Comment: I believe you need to put a `flex: 1` in the container styling

Comment: @JoelHager Could you please be more specific to which container I need to give `flex:1` ?

Comment: Whatever is nested under the red background. Looks like the switch navigator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding `position:absolute` to `tabBarOptions`

```
tabBarOptions={{
    showLabel: false,
    style: {
  backgroundColor: "blue",
  marginBottom: 15,
  borderRadius: 15,
  marginHorizontal: 10,
  height:60,
  position: 'absolute',
    },
```

[image]